# Does the absence of pairwise association imply the absence of joint association?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that we have three random variables $x, y_1$, and $y_2$. It holds that

- $p(x|y_1) = p(x)$, and
- $p(x|y_2) = p(x)$.

Does that imply $p(x|y_1, y_2) = p(x)$?

Note that association measures one-sided dependence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and elementary events are equally likely. Also, let $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{1,3\}$, $C=\{2,3\}$. Then $A, B, C $ are pairwise independent, that is $\mathbb{P} (A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)*\mathbb{P}(B)$, $\mathbb{P} (B\cap C)=\mathbb{P}(B)*\mathbb{P}(C)$ and $\mathbb{P} (A\cap C)=\mathbb{P}(A)*\mathbb{P}(C)$. But $\mathbb{P} (A\cap B \cap C)=\mathbb{P} (\phi)=0\neq \mathbb{P}(A)*\mathbb{P}(B)*\mathbb{P}(C)$.

So pairwise independence does not imply mutual independence.